# Accessing Classes via Variable

Tags: python, scripting

I am attempting to make a small game, and what I will be doing is using classes to dictate the stats of the user's preferred class. I need to make the classes so when it comes time to fight a monster (which will also be in it's own class), I will be able to have their stats callable.

This may be a "big picture" problem, but to avoid writing the code three times (for each class), I only want to call the variable "chosenClass.HP" instead of "Mage.HP" because if I did it that way, I would need to have a bunch of if statements for each class among the story. There must be a better way.

I have worked on this both ways, and I hate having to write

```
if userChoice is 'Mage':
   HP = 150
```

I have looked around at the self.something, but I don't completely understand how that works. If that is the required or recommended solution, what is the best resource for learning?

```
print("Welcome to the game")

name = input("Choose your name\n")
print(name)

class Warrior:
    HP = 100
    ATK = 200
    DEF = 0

class Mage:
    HP = 100
    ATK = 200
    DEF = 0

class Rouge:
    HP = 150
    ATK = 250
    DEF = 100

user_class = input("Choose a class between Warrior, Mage, or Rouge\n")
print(user_class)

while(user_class != 'Warrior' and user_class != 'Mage' and user_class != 'Rouge'):
    print("You did not choose from the required classes, try again")
    user_class = input()

theClass = user_class()
theClass.HP = 1000
```

My error that I get from this code is:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
I understand it's being given a String, but it's a variable. Why is it causing problems?

Any recommendations to make this program better?

Comment: `Mage` is a variable; `'Mage'` (the value of `user_class`) is not.

Comment: I would recommend you look into inheritance of classes if you want to avoid defining similar definitions three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_class` returns a string and not an actual `Class` that you've defined above. This is because `input()` returns a string and you store that in `user_class`. In order to create a new instance of the classes you created in your code need to instantiate the class using some sort of logic based on the player's input such as:

```
if user_class.lower() == 'warrior':
    theClass = Warrior()

theClass.HP = 1000
```

Obviously this wouldn't be the best way but is just an example to show how to instantiate the class.

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't seem to work. I am receiving the same error.

Comment: What exactly did you run? I just tested again on mine and it ran fine

Comment: Wow.. Uh, okay. I tried it again and now it's good. Thank you for the solution! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need a mapping of strings to classes if you want to create an instance like this.

```
pc_classes = {'Mage': Mage, 'Warrior': Warrior, 'Rogue': Rogue}
while True:
    try:
        user_class = input("Enter Mage, Warrior, or Rogue)
    if user_class in pc_classes:
        break

pc = pc_classes[user_class]()
```